# Best Practise to transform Cartesian Coordinates to Screen Coordinates in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I am drawing a bunch of points to a wpf canvas. The points have cartesian coordinates. So i wrote a method to transform them to screen coordinates with the attached method.

it's working but i wonder if thats best practise or if there is a native method to do it?

```
 private Point TransformPoint(Point pBase)
 {
      // just some debug values
      int dCanvasWidth = 400;
      int dCanvasHeight = 400;
      double dMaxXCartesian = 1000;
      double dMaxYCartesian = 1000;
      // transformation
      double dScreenX = pBase.X / dMaxXCartesian * dCanvasWidth;
      double dScreenY = dCanvasHeight - pBase.Y / dMaxYCartesian * dCanvasHeight;
      return new Point(dScreenX, dScreenY);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is. You set up the transformation matrix once, then simply call its Transform() function with a whole array of points:

```
matrix.Transform(point[]);
```